# How to Disable auto watch in Npm

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I use node `'npm start'` to compile my Angular 2 project, But I need to compile .tsc files manually not using the auto watch.

I want to do that as I am using ASP.net with Angular and for a reason, solution don't see my changes

Comment: What is your ``start``command ?

Comment: @AhmedRagheb what do you define for `npm start`? it's just a shortcut for command that you defined in package.json

Comment: Ok i got it .. my command is `tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" `, i think i should remove -w ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### How to turn off live reload for `npm start` in an Angular project:

In your `package.json` file, set the `--live-reload=false` option for `ng serve`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

place a bs-config.json file in your project folder containing:

```
{
 "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css}"]
}
```

so it won't watch js files anymore